# Tezos - Liquidity deploy contract error

Tags: liquidity, contract, deploy, babylon

I got an error and I don't know how to handle.

I wrote a smart contract in liquidity and script check and so works well.

The command to deploy is:

```
liquidity --node http://192.168.1.150:7732 --network tezos --amount 2tz --fee 0tz --delegatable --private-key edskXXXXXXXXXXXX --source tz1Uh9BWPPH9KDA3rX8XDG1JMtQyvtg5V9ju test.liq --deploy "tz1UB1ZdVU2ffdssji8qyUubeiAT8M4WdD56"
```

The error is:

```
Main contract Test
Main contract Test
Request Error (code 400):
Failed to parse the request body: Missing object field chain_id
```

The version of liquidity is:

```
1.055
```

In the `--help` option I never see a chain_id option.

Someone knows to help?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure that the liquidity language is still maintained for Tezos. You could try opening an issue here: https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity/issues 
From reading the source of liquidity, it seems that the deploy gets the head of the chain and attempts to read its `chain_id`, without finding it. Are you running a node? What is the result of running `tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head` ?

Comment: Hehey, ok if this is true, it is sad. but i found a solution; liquidity -> .lig -> .tz and deploy with tezos-client. :)

Comment: Do you wanna post that as an answer? Otherwise I'll do it :)

Comment: hehe sorry :) i will do :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hehey, ok if this is true, it is sad. but i found a solution; liquidity -> .liq -> .tz and deploy with tezos-client. :) – candlez Jan 6 at 15:00