# Liquidity for tezos : how to install liquidity without this bug?

Tags: liquidity

I have a problem to install liquidity.

I tried what is displayed on https://liquidity-lang.org/doc/installation/index.html

But it raises the error  :

```
m@samsung:~/liquidity$ make build-deps
opam switch create . 4.07.1 --no-install
opam: unknown option `--no-install'.
Usage: opam switch [OPTION]... [COMMAND] [ARG]...
Try `opam switch --help' or `opam --help' for more information.
Makefile:70 : la recette pour la cible « _opam » a échouée
make: *** [_opam] Erreur 1
```

Could you just make an apt repository for liquidity ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [Liquidity repository](https://github.com/OCamlPro/liquidity) the last update was 3 years ago. Liquidity is not maintained anymore and I doubt that someone writes smart contracts in Liquidity for Tezos. Also on tezos.com and opentezos.com there is no mention of Liquidity but other smart contract languages.

You have for Smart contracts the following languages:

- [LIGO](https://ligolang.org/)
- [SmartPy](https://smartpy.io/)
- [Archetype](https://archetype-lang.org/)

If you still want to experiment with Liquidity that is not maintaned and outdated, then maybe this [workaround](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/tezos-liquidity-deploy-contract-error) here can help?